# python: pass a double-single quote string to sql query

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working with a python application that uses textual SQL for postgresql queries.
I would like to use strings similar to this ''mykey,myval''` for my sql query. The code is wrapped into a function which should append the string to an hstore. Here is the code:

```
 def _myfunc_for_hstore(connection, inst, key, val):

     value = "''{},{}''".format(key,val) # build the string to insert

     connection.execute('''SELECT master_modify_multiple_shards
                  ('UPDATE  my_table 
                  SET values = values || hstore(%(value)s) 
                  WHERE object_id  %(object_id)s');''',
                  {'object_id': inst.object_id, 'value': value})
```

Running the code produces:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "mykey"
SET values = values || hstore('''''mykey...
```

So I guess the problem is the way I build the string:

```
value = "''{},{}''".format(key,val)
```

What is the right way to pass to the sql query the right value: ''mykey,myval''?
thanks

Comment: use "repr((key,value))"  this should work

Answer (score 0):

Actually I removed entirely the

```
value = "''{},{}''".format(key,val) # build the string to insert
```

and used directly key and value. This work fine:

```
def _myfunc_for_hstore(connection, inst, key, val):
    connection.execute('''SELECT master_modify_multiple_shards
              ('UPDATE  my_table 
              SET values = values || hstore('%(key)s','%(val)s') 
              WHERE object_id  %(object_id)s');''',
              {'object_id': inst.object_id, 'key': key, 'val':val})
```